# Forum access based on role

Tags: nodes

I cant figure out to hide forum sections based on role. I only want clan leaders to see the clan leaders section, squad members to see their own squad section etc. I already have the roles set up, but I can't figure out how to restrict access to container/forum based on those roles.

Someone mentioned the taxonomy access control module. But that seems *really* overyly complicated for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version of Drupal you are using, but have you looked at the [Forum Access](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access) module?  For D6 there is a stable release and the D7 version is in Beta. The module is also very straight-forward

From the module's page:

> This module changes your forum administration page to allow you to set
>   forums private. You can control what user roles can view, edit,
>   delete, and post to each forum. You can also give each forum a list of
>   users who have administrative access on that forum (AKA moderators).
>
> This module requires the [ACL](http://drupal.org/project/acl) module in order to function. The D7
>   version also requires the [Chain Menu Access API](http://drupal.org/project/chain_menu_access) module.
>
> Forum Access is compatible with the core Forum module, [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum),
>   and [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access), [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) as well as all other well-behaved
>   node access modules.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine, thankyou :)